# Renormalizing Legendre polynomials to $P_n(0)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

One way to define the Legendre polynomials is with the recurrence relation
$$(n+1)P_{n+1} (x) = (2n+1)xP_{n} (x)-nP_{n-1} (x),$$
with $P_0(x)=1$ and $P_1(x)=x$. This standardization is normalized so that $P_n(1)=1$ for all $n$, and so that the polynomials are orthogonal on $[-1,1]$. I'm trying to form an iterative method to solve $Ax=b$, and one thing that came up is that I need the Legendre polynomials renormalized such that $P_n(0)=1$ instead of $P_n(1)=1$.

However  I don't know how to do this. Simply dividing the polynomial by $P_n(0)$ for example is not very helpful, because half the degrees of the Legendre polynomial already have $P_n(0)=0$ and so I'd be dividing by zero.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what kind of $\;A x = b\;$ systems you are trying to solve with this method?

Comment: Basically anything iterative methods based on Krylov subspaces are good for. In short I'd like to use orthogonal polynomials for the Krylov space in doing $P(A)b$. I'm being somewhat vague, however, because I wouldn't want the problem statement to stray off-topic.

Comment: You cannot have $ P_n (0)=1 $.

Comment: There is a technique called "Chebyshev Acceleration" used for the iterative solution of systems of linear equations. It is based on Chebyshev polynomials.
Both Chebyshev and Legendre polynomials are instances of the Jacobi polynomials. Are you trying to implement something similar? Oh I see the question was posted last December.

Answer (score 0):

Legendre polynomials are solutions of the Legendre differential equation $$[(1-x^2)y']' + n(n+1)y = 0$$
Applying the series method by substituting $y=\sum_{j=0}^n a_jx^j$, one finds a recurrence relation between the coefficients $a_j$ that lead to the elementary solutions $P_n(x)$ that are polynomials of degree $n$ which contain only odd-numbered or only even-numbered powers of $x$. Obviously then, $P_n(0)=0$ if $n$ is odd, and it is easy to derive from the recurrence relation that $P_n(0)\not=0$ if $n$ is even. Solutions equal to non-terminating series also exist and are usually written as $Q_n(x)$, which are technically equal to a polynomial of degree $n-1$ of again only odd or only even-powers of $x$, plus a term containing a factor $ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$. As this factor evaluates to $0$ when $x=0$, it is again obvious that $Q_n(0)=0$ if $n$ is even, and again it is simple to see that $Q_n(0)\not=0$ if $n$ is odd.

A general solution of the Legendre differential equation then is a linear combination of $P_n(x)$ and $Q_n(x)$, as the equation itself is a linear one:

$$y=f(x)=\alpha P_n(x) +\beta Q_n(x)$$
for which it is clear that by choosing appropriate values for $\alpha$ or $\beta$, it is possible to achieve $f(0)=1$.

Thus, you will not be able to use $P_n(x)$ (nor $Q_n(x)$), but if you can use more general solutions to the Legendre differential equation instead, then functions $R_n(x)$ are available which are multiples of either $P_n(x)$ or $Q_n(x)$ (alternatively P or Q for each next value of n), and have $R_n(0)=1$.

But, obviously, the recurrence relation above will not hold for the $R_n(x)$, as from it follows for instance that $2R_2(0) = -R_0(0)$.
If you need this recurrence relation to hold and can also live with the fact that just $R_n(0) \not=0$, then you can use
$$R_0(x) = P_0(x) + Q_0(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$
$$R_1(x) = P_1(x) + Q_1(x) = x + \frac{x}{2}ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) -1$$
$R_n(x)$ for $n>=2$ to be derived by applying the recurrence relation
$$(n+1)R_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1)xR_n(x) - nR_{n-1}(x)$$
which you will quickly understand leads to the same as saying that
$$R_n(x) = P_n(x) + Q_n(x)$$

I hope this helps!